# How to set timer in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a new in angular js and in this moment I am developing a simple aplication to organize tasks that employees doing during the day.
First of all, the user set the customer, description and start the timer to count, when the task is finished, the employees click in finish and the task is closed, but I make a new function if the user close accidentally the tab, when reopen the tab, the user can get the old data (localstorage), but I dont know how to set the time when the user click to active the old time.

I am using this timer (http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#) to develop the counter in this app.

Anyone help me solve it?

Comment: Why are you using a timer? Save the timestamp (`Date.now()`) on start in localstorage and save it again on "end" event.  Presto end - start = time worked.

Comment: I use the timer cause it's important to show the user the time that task is during

Comment: Ok. My answer would still work. Just check for a "start" in localstrage on page load (or reload) and run the timer using the stored start value

Comment: @Alexander, You've asked a lot of questions and never marked any as correct? Theres a green tick next to all answers that you are meant to select to help others. Heres a helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/index.html#/timer-with-start-time), you can initialize the timer by setting the `start-time` attribute as the time in milliseconds. You can get this from any Date object with the `getTime()` function. What you need to do now is take this value, store it in `localStorage`, retrieve it later, and use it a the `start-time` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, My explain is wrong, I'd like to get my time (salved in localsotrage) and set the timer, my main doubt is how can I set the timer using the old time

Comment: @Alexander I've updated my answer to hopefully address your problem better.